# Is it possible for LogSubscribe wss to miss out on new logs from the tracked addresses?

Tags: websocket

I tried to use the log subscribe wss to track activities for a given address. I noticed that sometimes it would not push me all the confirmed log events. Is it because of the node that I'm using isn't very good e.g I'm getting rate limited? do you guys have similar issues with LogSubscribe?

Comment: This is most likely dependent on your RPC provider, I suggest you ask them first and then come back in case they say it's not due to them, in which case you should provide your code as well.

Comment: Would you consider adding a code snippet to your question? If there's an error in your code, someone might be able to spot it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but try setting the commitment to confirmed.
eg: websocket.logs_subscribe(filter_=RpcTransactionLogsFilterMentions(address), commitment="confirmed")